# Hint request for: under some assumptions, almost every point has a dense orbit in a compact metric space

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am new to Ergodic Theory and I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $(X, B, \mu)$ be a probability space where $\mu(U) > 0$ for every open set $U$, and let $f:X \to X$ be a surjective, ergodic measure preserving transformation. Then almost every point of $X$ has a dense orbit.

I am looking for any kind of hint on how to prove this, but if you could give me a hint on how to continue my approach below, that would be extremely helpful. Thank you very much!

**Partial Solution:**

Let $(B_n)$ be a base for $X$. The set of points which have a dense orbit is
$$\{x \in X| \ \ \forall n \ge 1 \ \exists m \ge 0: \ f^m(x) \in B_n \}$$
which can be written as
$$\bigcap_{n \ge 1} \bigcup_{m \ge 0}f^{-m}(B_n).$$

We want to show that this set has measure $1$. To do this, it is sufficient to show that $\bigcup_{m \ge 0}f^{-m}(B_n)$ has measure $1$ for each $n$. However, I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: The statement of the theorem appears to be missing a hypothesis.  Do you mean "... and let $f:X\to X$ be an **ergodic** measure preserving transformation."?  If so, here is a hint. Prove the contrapositive: if there is a positive measure set of $x$ having non-dense orbit, then $f$ is not ergodic.

Comment: Can you prove that $\bigcup_{m \ge 0}f^{-m}(B_n)$ is open and invariant?

Comment: @Ruy Ohh thanks that is a nice argument! $\bigcup_{m \ge 0}f^{-m}(B_n)$ because $f$ is continuous and preimages of open sets are open. And if we can show that set is invariant, then is must have measure $0$ or $1$, but since open sets get positive measure, it must have measure $1$. However, I ran into a problem with showing it's invariant. We have $$f^{_1}(\bigcup_{m \ge 0} f^{-m}(B_n)) = \bigcup_{m \ge 0}f^{-m-1}(B_n)$$ which I think is a subset of, but not necesarily equal to, $\bigcup_{m \ge 0} f^{-m}(B_n) $.

Comment: @JohnGriesmer Yes thank you I forgot that hypothesis. I will try it using your hint also.

Comment: @Blue You almost finished. If $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq A$, then since $f$ is measure-preserving, we must have $f^{-1}(A)=A$ up to measure $0$ sets, and so the measure of $A$ is $0$ or $1$.